# How to get a specific version from Team Foundation Server2013 "History View"?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I'm currently using VSS for source version control.
We are currently building the source for version control in TFS2013 in the future.

please tell me.

In the Source Control Explorer, place the cursor on the "Revert to Past Version" source, click "Right Click" and then "View History" to get the past version. The capture operation cannot be performed because it involves conflicting edits. "Is displayed. See image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai0Ju.png)

When I checked in, Team Explorer said, "The file was not checked in because there were conflicting changes. These conflicting changes were automatically resolved. If any changes remain, Please check in again "is displayed.

When I clicked "Check in" again, it said "All changes are either unchanged files or locks. It was undone by the change server" and I couldn't get the previous version.
I don't know why I can't get the past version.
Please tell me what to do.
Thank you.

Comment: Probably you have some pending changes before you tried to rever to past version. Try to Undo any pending changes first than start with "Revert to Past Version". Please note that doing so you will lose any Pending Changes you might have. In order to preserve them you might Shelve them before Undoing them.

Comment: As VSS as been completely unsupported for many years you are incurring a significant business risk by staying with it. Have you raised this risk with your executive team? Do they know that their organisational asset is at risk? Please try to use other source control, like TFVC, Git.

Comment: Trick, Leo Ryu-MSFT, thank you for your answers.
Sorry for the late reply.

I tried "Undo pending changes" before "Revert to previous version", but it was grayed out and could not be clicked.

Even if I execute "Get latest version", "It is the latest version" is displayed.

I've been searching on the internet, but I don't know the cause.
I would appreciate it if you could teach me